# Does Apple provide an index of localized terms that it uses?

Tags: iphone, ios, localization

Does Apple provide developers a set of standard terms in differing languages?  The reason why I ask is that I'm having portions of my application localized and want standard terminology consistently applied throughout the app.  I have utilized some tactics to do this with terms like 'Loading...' by changing the language on my device and observing how Apple has interpreted those terms in other languages.  This has only gotten me so far however, and a resource that I can give a translator would go a long way in creating a seamless experience with the consistent application of terminology.

Comment: Microsoft do, in case that helps: http://www.microsoft.com/Language/ I imagine they'd use the same terms as Apple although you won't get translations of the Apple-specific UI elements obviously.

Comment: All of UIKit is localized. That doesn't help much as there is limited vocabulary (edit/delete, favorites, contacts, etc.) but it is less things to localize. Ie: don't change the title of the provided UIBarButtonItem Edit button.

Comment: @Rup Good idea.  Many of the things I am looking for are iOS specific, like 'Push Notifications', for example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It has been two and a half years since posting my radar, but Apple has finally posted its iOS glossaries:

You can download them from developer.apple.com, or use this link to quickly find them:

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Glossaries%20-%20iOS

**EDIT 29 FEB 2020**: This link is still valid and the glossaries have been updated on 15 JAN 2020 with everything updated for iOS 13.3.

Comment: I checked the documents provided against iOS 10. The documents are not actively updated.

Comment: It would be nice to have some explanation on how to use the glossaries. After downloading them, I don't know how to look up a word.

Answer (score 7):

At WWDC this year I went to the Localization Lab to get an answer to this question, since a bona fide answer from Apple was needed.

From one of their head cheeses in localization he told me that currently there are not any publicly available resources for download for iOS or Snow Leopard.  He did tell me, though, that these resources were slated for release in the coming weeks after WWDC.

This answer will be updated when the information becomes available.

**UPDATE 19 JUN 2012:** Wow, it has been a whole year now!  Obviously Apple didn't come through for us 'in a few weeks'.  I did talk to them again this year and was given a contact to follow up with via email.  I explained that they made a claim to have it last year and this was the response I got:

> I did check with the documentation folks and found that they're still
>   planning on doing this but it's fallen behind other priorities. If you
>   haven't already done so, would you mind filing a bug report about
>   this? That's one of the best ways to convey the desire to the
>   appropriate people. While I've relayed this feedback to some people
>   it's always best to have a bug report directly from folks outside of
>   Apple. Feel free to forward me the bug number and I'll keep an eye on
>   it.

**Our best bet at this point is to keep filling bug reports so that this gets more attention.  Just for the record, I did file a bug report last year.**

Comment: +1 for talking to Apple about this. I'm very curious whether they really release something (and how useful it will be).

Comment: Apple never released this (here's hoping for WWDC 2013!) but we put together our own iOS multilingual glossary. We're a group of localization professionals, so we use this internally but it's ready for public consumption. Please help contribute suggestions and corrections: http://www.ibabbleon.com/glossary

Answer (score 5):

Apple provides a number of [translation resources that you can download](http://developer.apple.com/internationalization/downloads/) which may or may not be useful. One of these is AppleGlot, a tool for replacing strings in application resources. A number of XML-based glossaries for different languages are also available, but they're specific to AppleGlot. You may be able to make AppleGlot work for you, or you might just want to extract what you can from the language glossaries. AppleGlot and the glossaries were created to support translation of MacOS applications, so the terms are related to MacOS X and not iOS. Nevertheless, I think it's worth a look.

Comment: A lot of what I'm looking for is iOS specific, like 'Push Notifications', for example.

Comment: AppleTrans on that page says it has an online corpora so there's an outside chance that's actually up-to-date with iOS etc. - worth a look? If not this then it's probably worth asking Apple Developer Support if you can - they really ought to provide this stuff.