# Localization for common UI strings

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, localization

I have strings in my file that I am localizing. Many of these are common and used already throughout iOS. E.g. "saving", "loading", "go back", "favorites", "take a photo". In the interest of providing a consistent user experience with other apps and the built-in apps, is there a way to hook into these localizations? Or is there a list of translations somewhere so I can copy-paste in the same wording others are using?

Comment: There's an app in the Mac App Store called "Generate Localizable Strings", check it out.

Comment: I very much doubt there is a standard set of translations, but it would be nice if there was!

Comment: I don't know how good the translations are, but this site provides some common localization strings in an easy to look up format: https://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/mobile-app-keywords/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an iOS device you can discover them yourself.  Start with an App that you know, say in American English, change your default language, start the App again and note the mappings.

Also, check here: [Does Apple provide an index of localized terms that it uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5897777/1286639)

You can find [Third Party localization vendors](https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/).